# How to reference a library class into a web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, class-library

[image]

I create a class library for my client application and web service. In it, I create some class which I'd like to use it in the web service, but when I add the reference, the solution explorer shows the a yellow warning. But I don't know what is happening.

I'm receiving two warnings:

> Error The type or namespace name 'Usuario' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace 'RedMov' (are
> you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you trying to Consume the Web Service Reference or an individual Assembly.. sounds like you need to add a Reference to the proper .DLL and or Add a Web Reference what is known as Consuming Web Reference any additional code sample as to how you are trying to implement this would also be helpful

Comment: I'm adding a DLL to the web service

Comment: do you have a warning/error in your error list?

Comment: Did you add it as a project reference, or did you browse to the dll file and add it that way?

Comment: @CodingGorilla I added it as a project reference

Comment: Did you create the web service as a Web Application Project or a Web Site?

Comment: @DarfZon If you attempt to compile, what (if any) error message do you get?

Comment: As a ASP WebService Application

Comment: Check that the .NET version of the `Core` assembly you're trying to reference isn't higher than that of the WebService assembly.

Comment: Ohhh that's right. My class library has 4.5 .NET Version and my web service 3.5. Just for be sure, WebService cannot upgrade to 4 version right?

Comment: I don't see why it couldn't be in .NET 4. The main thing here is that the class library needs to be the same .NET version as that of the WebService (or lower).

Answer (score 1):

Check that the .NET version of the Core assembly you're trying to reference isn't higher than that of the WebService assembly.

.NET is backwards compatible, so you can reference a .NET 3.5 assembly in a .NET 4 project, but not the other way around.